# How can I perform element-wise multiplication for Ruby arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, elementwise-operations

courses, credits and points are Ruby arrays with an equal size.

```
gpa = (([credits, courses, points].transpose.map {|x| x.reduce(:*)}).inject{|sum,x| sum + x }).round(2)
```

This method prompted an error message when I was trying to run it.

**Error message:**

```
in 'each': undefined method '*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Looks good to me. (by the way, `inject` and `reduce` are synonyms, use one or the other but not both, for clarity). **The problem is in your data**

Comment: please put the arrays if possible.

Comment: separate that long code into different lines so you can easily pinpoint where the error is.

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk Thanks for raising up the synonyms. Yeah you're right. Some unexpected errors within the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that some of the data is `nil`.

Perhaps you can attempt to force the data into floats.

It's not ideal, as you might end up with silent errors, but it's worth a shot.

try:

```
[credits, courses, points].transpose.map {|a| a.map {|n| n.to_f} } .map { |x| x.reduce(:*) } .inject{|sum, x| sum + x} .round(2)
```

It works for me even with strings and weird data (although the incompatible data is simply converted to zeros, effecting the math).

Comment: Thanks, I found the error. It actually caused by some invalid data.

Comment: @JohnsonYeap Your welcome. I'm happy you found the error. Good luck with your coding.